# TENGO ESTE PEQUEÑO ERROR EN ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, java-8

ESTOY REALIZANDO UN APLICACION EN ANDROID STUDIO DE DOMICILIOS, EN LA CUAL IMPORTE LAS LIBRERIAS DE ANDROID-IMAGE-CROPER, PERO AL REALIZAR LA EJCUCION DE LA APP ME ENVIA EL ERROR QUE ESCRIBIRE EN BREVEDAD, Y LA VERDAD LLEVO DIAS INTENTANDO ARREGLARLO Y NADA ME FUNCIONA, PERO CUANDO QUITO O REMUEVO LAS IMPLEMENTACIONES LA APP FUNCIONA NORMAL, Y DE VERDAD NECESITO ESA IMPLEMENTACION YA QUE ESTA ME PERMITIRA MODIFICAR EL TAMAÑO DE LA IMAGEN DE LOS USUARIOS, O EN SU EFECTO ME RECOMEDARIAN ALGUNA ATERNATIVA EN CASO DE QUE EL PROBLEMA NO TENGA SOLUCION, GRACIAS POR LA ATENCION PRESTADA Y FELIZ RESTO DE DIA.

ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME ENVIA:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

```
1) EL CODIGO QUE TENGO EN EL BUILD.GRADLE(ESTE ES EL DEL PROYECTO) 
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'

    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
//    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


2) EL CODIGO QUE TENGO EN EL BUILD.GRADLE(ESTE ES EL DEL MODULO DEL PROYECTO)
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android{
    compileSdk 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.domiciliosblader"
        minSdk 19
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:20.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    //implementation 'com.github.jesseruder:Android-Image-Cropper:3.0.+'

}

ME GUSTARIA RECIBIR AYUDA CON ESTE PROCESO, YA QUE ME ESTOY RETRASANDO MUCHO Y EH PROBADO MUCHOS METOOS PERO NADA FUNCIONA, SOY NUEVO EN ANDROID STUDIO POR LO QUE NO TENGO MUCHA EXPERIENCIA.
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné: quizá sea una animalada lo que hice, pero lo pongo por si le sirve a alguien. Después de probar todo lo que encontré y que nada funcionara, lo que hice fue: -Crear un nuevo proyecto. -Modificar todos los archivos gradle del proyecto que tenía el problema hasta dejarlos igual a los del nuevo proyecto. -Sincronizar. -comentar todas las importaciones que marcaban error en cada activity (import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity...(y otras que tenían que ver con kotlin)) -importar lo que me pedía importar. -la "magia" de kotlin de señalar los objetos de los xml se perdió, así que creé las variables correspondientes y use el mismo findViewById que usaba en java.